# Aptana 3.2.0 Plugin for Eclipse. Javascript code completion issue

Tags: eclipse, aptana, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse PDT 3.0.2 All In Ones installed with Aptana Studio 3.2.0 plug-in. When I create a web project (Project Natures/Web is set to primary) with javascript file and try to use code completion (ctrl + space) this results in "No Default proposals" message. I can right-click on project and select "Configure/Convert to JavaScript Project" though but this is the feature of Eclipse not Aptana.

P.S. CSS and HTML code completion works fine.

Comment: What are the other natures of your project?

Comment: None at the moment. I am just testing basic js functionality in conjuction with XHTML & CSS. BTW I have a Javascript Editor as a default editor for .js files (preferences window: http://savepic.su/2225780.gif) and therefore I have doubts that this is Aptana js editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That did it. I have changed an editor associated with .js files to *JavaScript Source editor* instead of *JavaScript Editor* which was set as default at installation. It would be nice if they added "Aptana" after the name of editor to distinguish it from other editors.