# Aptana plugin for eclipse javascript - error identification and autocompletion

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, aptana

I installed the Aptana plugin 3.2.0 for the Eclipse IDE For javascript, but the features it promises are not apparent. Even the simplest syntax error (random strings inside the code) doesn't trigger it. Also, it doesn't perform autocompletion. I know for a fact that it's installed correctly onto Eclipse because I can change its settings in the Preferences tab.

Any help with that? I'd like it to work as smoothly as the Eclipse Java editor works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change an editor associated with .js files to *JavaScript Source editor* instead of *JavaScript Editor* which was set as default at installation to make code completion work (I had the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603944/1038266). Go to *Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations* find .js and change editor to JavaScript Source Editor (default button).